# execute sp_executesql error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a formula.And formula is a nvarhcar like '2+5+8/3'

I want to make a function that after calculated my formula give me a result like

```
alter FUNCTION Calculate(@Formula NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result2 FLOAT,@Query NVARCHAR(50)
SET @Query=N'select @Result='+@Formula
execute sp_executesql @Query ,N'@Result float output',@Result=@Result2 OUTPUT
RETURN @Result2
END
```

function create successfully but I use the function

select dbo.Calculate('2+5+9')
I get a error that
'Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.'
How can make a function like this?Thanks a lot

Thanks your answer but I will use it in a select query,
my data like that

```
Name Formula Result
dd    2+3+5
gg    1+4+7
hh    2*8
jj    3*9
Kl    8*9
```

I have to calculate Result column a select
like

select
Name,dbo.Calculate(Formula) as Result
Is there another way to make it

Comment: If it must be a function, you'll have to create a clr function. You can't call procedures or execute dynamic sql in a typical udf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like bellow :

```
Create Proc Proc1

As

Begin

Select 'SQL Server'

End

Go
```

Create a Function

```
Create Function dbo.Function1() Returns @Result Table
(

    Result Varchar(100)

 )

 As

Begin   

Insert @Result

SELECT * from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI10', 'Server=<SERVERNAME>;UID=<LOGIN>;Pwd=     <PASSWORD>;',

        'Exec dbo.Proc1') AS C 

Return

 end

  Go
```

Execute function

```
  Select * from dbo.Function1()
```

Hopes this helps you....

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to create a `FUNCTION` but a `PROCEDURE` because functions have the limitation that they generally cannot use `EXECUTE`. They are meant to be side-effect free and `EXEC` may be used to circumvent that guarantee.

Comment: Thanks your answer but I will use it in a select query,
my data like that
Name Formula Result
dd    2+3+5
gg    1+4+7
hh    2*8
jj    3*9
Kl    8*9
I have to calculate Result column a select
like

select
Name,dbo.Calculate(Formula) as Result
Is there another way to make it

Comment: That's going to be difficult. Search for "SQL Server execute procedure in query". You won't find an easy answer because there is none.